# 500 Internal Server Error - Any Upload via Wordpress Admin Panel

Tags: wordpress, iis

I am running a Wordpress website on Windows Server 2012 on VPS. I am receiving 500 Internal Server Error when I try to upload anything such as theme, media, plugin via adming panel of wordpress site. I am wondering why is this happenning.

What I could find so far is:

```
Most likely causes:
IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred.
IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.
IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.
The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.
The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.

Things you can try:
Ensure that the NTFS permissions for the web.config file are correct and allow access to the Web server's machine account.
Check the event logs to see if any additional information was logged.
Verify the permissions for the DLL.
Install the .NET Extensibility feature if the request is mapped to a managed handler.
Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click here.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     FastCgiModule
Notification       ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler    PHP-php
Error Code     0x80004005
Requested URL     
Physical Path      
Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous

More Information:
This error means that there was a problem while processing the request. The request was received by the Web server, but during processing a fatal error occurred, causing the 500 error.
View more information »

Microsoft Knowledge Base Articles:

294807
```

Comment: Check event viewer to see if there are any errors logged. Post it here in case you need help.

Comment: I cannot see in event viewer any logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found the solution after a day of research. In my case the error was the PHP Support. I changed the PHP support in Plesk from Fast CGI to CGI then boom. It worked. Hope it will help you some how.